# org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException when running runnable jar with java 8

Tags: java, unmarshalling, saxparseexception

I am exporting my project as runnable jar and execute in java 8 environment. But I am getting

```
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/sec
ure-processing
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source
)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown
Source)
```

I tried with xercesImpl.2.11.0 and got :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 63; columnNumber: 9; The string "--"
 is not permitted within comments.]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalExcept
ion(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.cr
eateUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:)
```

Please provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below error comes if something is wrong in your XML or HTML:

```
The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
```

An HTML comment begins with `"<!--",` ends with `"-->"` and does not contain `"--"` or `">"` anywhere in the comment.

Go through this URL([HTML Comments](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html)) for more details.